# Get HTML content with variable tags and extract innertext with VBA for EXcel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

I would like to get just the **number between "ca." and "m²"** from the text-row. How to do it with VBA to avoid additional string formulas in Excel?

Problem is also that innertext in HTML content is sometimes in **tr.td.p-tag***, other times only in **tr.td-tag** (without p) and sometimes in **tr.td.b-tag**, in this case "Description" is replaced with "Appointment" in the according td-tag.

Is there a VBA code to check&extract with queryselectorall? Something like:

```
myString01 = html.queryselectorall(tr td).item(x).innertext

If InStr(myString, "DESCRIPTION") > 0 Then 
'NEED VBA CODE, value must be the number of innerText in td.p or td 
Else if 
   InStr(myString, "APPOINTEENT") > 0 Then 
'NEED VBA CODE, value must be the last word of innerText in td.b
end if
```

These are the 3 different snippets for the same property of different items:

```html
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">Description:</td>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<p>
textA textB textC ca. 140 m².
</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

```html
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">Description:</td>
<td valign="top" align="left">
textA textB textC ca. 85 m².
</td>
</tr>
```

```html
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left">Appointment</td>>
<td valign="top" align="left">
<b>
textA textB textC canceled!
</b>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: **1.** If you can identify the right *tr tag* and the only text in *td tag* or *p tag* is the same it's enough to get the `innertext` from the *tr tag*. Other tags inside the *tr tag* will be ignored than. **2.** Use `split()` with the `innertext` and get the second last element. Than you have what you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function **3.** If you need more infos it's always the same: Please post the url in question.

Comment: @Zwenn:Thanks! How to identify the TR-tags without any id, name etc? They are all just parents of TD-tags and children of table.tbody and their count is also always different.

Comment: Only you know the whole html. Trying to get the right table tag and extract all tr tags would be my approach. But I don't know if there are a way to identify the right table tag. Please look at point 3. of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the links to the detail documents during a post request then visit each of those links with internet explorer, ensuring to provide the right referer header; then use regex to grab that measurement.

TODO: Code really needs a re-factor as there is a lot going on in the main sub. Really each sub/function should be doing c. one thing.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetDataZvgPort()
    Const URL = "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    With xhr
        .Open "POST", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "land_abk=ni&ger_name=Peine&order_by=2&ger_id=P2411"
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable, r As Long, c As Long, headers(), row As MSHTML.HTMLTableRow
    Dim results() As Variant, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    headers = Array("Aktenzeichen", "Amtsgericht", "Objekt/Lage", "Verkehrswert in €", "Termin", "Pdf-Link", "Addit Info Link", "m²")

    ReDim results(1 To 100, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    Set table = html.querySelector("table")
    Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Dim lastRow As Boolean

    For Each row In table.Rows
        lastRow = False
        Dim header As String

        html2.body.innerHTML = row.innerHTML
        header = Trim$(row.Children(0).innerText)

        If header = "Aktenzeichen" Then          'start of new block. Assumes all blocks have this
            r = r + 1
            Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dict = GetBlankDictionary(headers)
            On Error Resume Next
            dict("Addit Info Link") = Replace$(html2.querySelector("a").href, "about:", "https://www.zvg-portal.de/")
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        If dict.Exists(header) Then dict(header) = Trim$(row.Children(1).innerText)

        If (header = vbNullString And html2.querySelectorAll("a").Length > 0) Then
            dict("Pdf-Link") = Replace$(html2.querySelector("a").href, "about:blank", "https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php")
            lastRow = True
        ElseIf header = "Termin" Then
            If row.NextSibling.NodeType = 1 Then lastRow = True
        End If

        If lastRow Then
            populateArrayFromDict dict, results, r
        End If
    Next

    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 1, 1 To r)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    
    Dim re As Object
    
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    With re
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\s([0-9.]+)\sm²"
    End With

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        
        For r = LBound(results, 1) To UBound(results, 1)
            
            If results(r, 7) <> vbNullString Then
                
                .Navigate2 results(r, 7), headers:="Referer: " & URL
                
                While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
 
                'On Error Resume Next
                results(r, 8) = re.Execute(.document.querySelector("#anzeige").innerHTML)(0).Submatches(0)
                'On Error GoTo 0
   
            End If
            
        Next
        
        .Quit
        
    End With
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub populateArrayFromDict(ByVal dict As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef results() As Variant, ByVal r As Long)
    Dim key As Variant, c As Long

    For Each key In dict.Keys
        c = c + 1
        results(r, c) = Replace$(dict(key), " (Detailansicht)", vbNullString)
    Next

End Sub

Public Function GetBlankDictionary(ByRef headers() As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long

    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        dict(headers(i)) = vbNullString
    Next

    Set GetBlankDictionary = dict
End Function
```

Comment: Nice. A little more complex than I thought ;-)

Comment: I still think there are easier ways. Python doesn't need browser automation for any of this. I can't quite pin down what extra info (except referer) that needs to go with a GET request to retrieve the information, in the later stages, without error.

Comment: @QHarr: You'll be 100% right without any doubt, but for my limited purposes this code is absolutely adequate....and I don't need to install all the Python modules. This VBA-code works PERFECTLY. I would never have come up with this or anything even slightly similar in two lifetimes. Just had to set .visible=false so that my parents don't have an epileptic seizure at the sight of all those open browser-tabs :-) THANKS!

Comment: I was quite proud when I learned to add .item(x) to queryselectorall. How should I have come up with **.pattern = "\s([0-9.]+)\sm²"**??? It almost reads (and feels) like e=mc²   **lol**

Comment: I don't think that is the reason as . is included in the character set.  See https://regex101.com/r/WAJqAh/1 . Please provide the exact string that is failing via pastebin.com or instructions on how to reach that result on the website.

Comment: The code works very well so far, but one line causes trouble: `.Pattern = "\s([0-9.]+)\sm²` only finds round m² values and ignores those with decimal places. **98 is extracted** but **98.2** is ignored, not only the decimal places but the entire value! Is there a way to adjust the code-line appropriately? THX

Comment: Have got it: instead of a dot I have to put a comma after the number! With [0-9,] it works! But, in case of: **Text...text WFL 61,94 m²; NFL 7 m²; text...text** just the first value 61,94 is extracted and here the further question arises how I can extract both values with a "+" in between into one field in order to subsequently transform them into a formula in Access with a preceding "=" and to bring them to the addition?

Comment: change the flag to global = true then you will need to cycle through the matches. `Dim matches As Object, match As Object: Set matches = re.execute(.......)` then `For Each match in Matches`. As you cycle through matches empty the extracted match value into an array. At the end join the array with `"=" & Join(arr, "+")` . The array you can `Dim arr()` at same time as `Dim matches`,  then after `Set Matches` line `ReDim arr(1 to matches.count)`   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Thanks I will do that but anyway the question: is this not a matter of 2 values in one array-field? because at https://regex101.com/r/WAJqAh/1 both values are matched. I had rather thought that the key point was in here: `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(...)` `With rs.` `AddNew` **`.Fields("zpm2") = results(r, 8)`**, so in the array-field **results(r, 8)**??

Comment: yes but you say you want a formula? So results(r,8) will be =  `"=" & Join(arr, "+")` At the end meant, at the end of cycling through matches.